# Three way join in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables titled "Guest", "Guest_Address" and "Acutal_Address". 
Guest_Address is a linking table between guest and acutal_address. 
This is what I have so far.

```
  SELECT GUEST_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_CODE,(GUEST_FNAME+' '+GUEST_LNAME) AS GUEST_NAMES
  FROM GUEST JOIN GUEST_ADDRESS 
  ON GUEST.ADDRESS_NUM = GUEST_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_NUM;
```

This only joins the Guest and Guest_address table, but I need to join Guest and Acutal_Address.
Here is the ERD. [image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you want to do is do an additional join to the actual_address table like so :

```
  SELECT GUEST_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_CODE,(GUEST_FNAME+' '+GUEST_LNAME) AS GUEST_NAMES
  FROM GUEST 
  JOIN GUEST_ADDRESS ON GUEST.ADDRESS_NUM = GUEST_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_NUM
  JOIN ACTUAL_ADDRESS ON GUEST_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_CODE = ACTUAL_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_CODE
```

Mind if I ask why you have that linking table? Can guests have multiple addresses? If that is the case I would change the join from `GUEST_ADDRESS` to `GUEST` based on `GUEST_ID`, rather than `ADDRESS_NUM` as using `ADDRESS_NUM` makes the relationship between the two tables a one-to-one relationship rather than one-to-many

Also worth noting that the query above will not return a record for the guest if there is no address in the `ACTUAL_ADDRESS` table or link in the `GUEST_ADDRESS` table due to the `JOIN`. If you want it to return guest details regardless of address you can simply change the `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 3):

There is a many-to-many relationship between `Guest` and `ActualAddress` via the auxilary table `GuestAddress`. So to join then all together into one set do:

```
select * 
from Guest 
left join GuestAddress on GuestAddress.Guest_ID = Guest.Guest_ID 
left join ActualAddress on ActualAddress.AddressCode = GuestAddress.Address_Code
```

Then use the `where` clause to filter the set down to a smaller one (sub-set), if need be