# How to combine the result of two queries into one resultset

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need your help in getting the result of two queries and to show it into one. I need to show the records:

Employee Name, salary, saving amount, deduction amount

The Employee Name and salary are stored in a table called "Employee" and the saving amount is stored in a table called "Saving" and the Deduction Amount is stored in the "Deduction" table. In Each table the "Employee Code" is the primary key.

The first query is:

```
select e.employee_name, e.salary, s.saving_amount
from Employee e, Saving s
where e.employee_code = s.employee_code
and saving_amount > 1000
```

And the second query is:

```
select e.employee_name, d.deduction_amount
from Employee e, deduction d
where e.employee_code = d.employee_code
```

Not all the employees have deductions, also not all the employees are having savings.

Now I need to show the result:

> Employee Name, salary, saving amount, deduction amount

```
     AAA             1000      2000          500
     BBB             5000      
     CCC             3000      1500
```

Comment: Do a three-way join. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266994/three-way-join-in-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you started.  You can complete the details.

```
from employee e left join savings s on e..employee_code = s.employee_code
and saving_amount > 1000

left join deduction d on e.employee_code = d.employee_code
```

This also assumes that not all employees have savings.

Comment: Can I use the union or you would prefer this? Also, I am using Oracle database and I think you are referring to Left Outer Join

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Not all the employees have deductions, also not all the employees are having savings. if this is what you want this query would do.

```
SELECT        Employee.employee_name, Saving.savings_amount, Deduction.employee_deduction, Employee.employee_salaray
```

FROM            Employee LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Deduction ON Employee.employee_code = Deduction.employee_code FULL OUTER JOIN
                         Saving ON Employee.employee_code = Saving.employee_code
--WHERE        (Saving.savings_amount > 1000)

This would produce this result:
employee_name                                      savings_amount        employee_deduction    employee_salaray

---

AAA                                                2000.00               500.00                1000.00
BBB                                                0.00                  NULL                  5000.00
CCC                                                1500.00               NULL                  3000.00